# Opening Visual Studio 2010 Solution In Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution file which has 10 in the lower left corner of the solution.  I only have VS2013 installed on my computer.  Anytime, I attempt to open the solution I get this error:

> One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly
>   Please see the Output Window for details

And the details in the output window are:

> C:\Users\Desktop\ERT - ERT-sdk\C#\4.0\Sample.csproj : error  
>  The project file could not be loaded. 
> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.  
>   C:\Users\Desktop\ERT - ERT-sdk\C#\4.0\Sample.csproj

What do I need to alter so I can load the solution and project files on my PC in VS2013?

**EDIT**
Below are the top 7 lines of the sample.csproj file.  If more lines are needed just let me know, thanks!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
<ProjectType>Local</ProjectType>
<ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
<SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
<ProjectGuid>{90CCE281-D71C-4EA6-9C17-A3C052B583D4}</ProjectGuid>
```

**EDIT 2**
Running it through an XML syntax-check on www.w3schools.com/xml/sml_validator.asp It throws the error:

```
Error on Line 1 at column 6:
XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

Comment: Newer versions of VS can usually open older project files just fine. When you looked at the line it was complaining about, did you see anything odd about the content? Maybe paste the first few lines of the file?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - would it be the 1st few lines of the solution file?  The Sample.csproj?

Comment: The error messages mention Sample.csproj so it's probably that file.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen -- see edit, those are top 7 lines of sample.csproj

Comment: Bizarre. That part looks OK to me. Could you run it through something that validates XML? At the simplest that would be loading it into an `XDocument` or something. Additionally you could look for stray invisible bad characters using a hex editor. But that's kind of far-fetched.

Comment: You lost me on loading it into an XDocument.  Never had to do that before...

Comment: I meant `XDocument` as in [this class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx). Using it would be a quick way to get an idea if the document is valid XML in the first place. Of course anything else that parses and validates XML would work. Even an online validator.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - see edit 2 please :)

Comment: The error message doesn't make sense based on what I've seen. Did you follow my other suggestion and look for out of place characters on the first line of thereabouts using a hex editor? Plain text editors don't always show you everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors messages point to garbage bytes at the beginning of the file. Could be a duplicate or two-fold encoded UTF-8 byte order mark.

Remove the garbage bytes using a binary safe editor such as a hex editor and you should be good to go.

Or even just make a copy, open it in an editor that definitely ignores those characters and copy and paste the entire content into your original file.

Comment: Did you do as the error message asks you to, i.e. right click the unloaded project on the list and click "reload"? If you edited it with the online hex editor and saved it from the browser, it's probably just Windows's idiotic "this file was downloaded from the internet" non-feature again.

Comment: That was it, I ended up rebooting and that remedied.